# Text indent a wrapped inline-block span

Tags: css

I am looking for a ***CSS-only*** solution to the following problem.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<p>
    <span>Some text</span>
    <span>Some text</span>
</p>
```

Both `<span>` elements are being displayed `inline-block`. How can I indent or add padding to the left side of the second `<span>` ***after*** it wraps to a new line?

---

It should look something like this before wrapping:

[image: before wrapping]

And like this after wrapping:

[image: after wrapping]

---

Assigning `padding-left` with a negative `text-indent` does not work since each `<span>` is essentially on its first line of text and indented individually.

See the following snippet and this ***[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ynjybdw/)*** for my code.

```css
p {
/*  Negative indent does not work since
    it applies to all spans individually
    text-indent: -5rem;
    padding-left: 5rem;
*/
}
span {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.span1 {
    background-color: green;
}
.span2 {
    background-color: blue;
/*  Same problem as when applied to paragraph
    text-indent: -5rem;
    padding-left: 5rem
*/
/*  Will be indented properly when wrapped, but
    we are left with unwanted space when not wrapped
    padding-left: 5rem;
*/
}
.span3 {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 5rem;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <span class="span1">Howdy,</span>
    <span class="span2">please indent me when I wrap!</span>
    <span class="span3">I should continue being indented.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Doubtful there is a CSS solution. CSS can't detect wrapping AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to come up with something close, with two possible drawbacks.  One issue with this approach is that the first span must be wider than the indent amount or the wrapping doesn't work exactly as expected.  The other is that the background-color does not extend to the left of the indented element:

The trick is to have a `margin-left` on the 2nd span and to have an offsetting negative `margin-right` on the first:

```
.span1 {
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: -5rem;
}
.span2 {
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 5rem;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ynjybdw/4

Comment: It looks like this may be as good as it gets. You can deal with the width issue by giving the first span a `min-width` equal to the indent. There may then be little bit of extra spacing here and there, but at least the wrap happens as it should. The background color I'll have to live without.